# Excel: pass workbook object from sub to userform

Tags: excel, vba

I want to pass two objects (one open workbook and other a table) from sub procedure to userform. I have made both of them global before the sub.

1. When I write just the two public declarations before Sub (they are set inside Sub),works good within Sub but when the userform initializes, it throws the error **"Object variable or with block variable not set"**

```
Public N As Workbook
Public E As ListObject
Sub...
```

2. I tried to set these two objects before Sub, the Sub doesn't run, throws compile error, **"Invalid outside procedure"**

```
Public N As Workbook
Set N = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New").Range("A1").Text)
Public E As ListObject
Set E = N.Sheets(1).ListObjects(1)
Sub...
```

How to pass object variables from Sub procedures to Userforms? Currently the only solution I see is to set the objects in both the Sub procedure and the Userform.

Comment: Is what you show to us the way you really tried? If yes, it is wrong... A `Public` variable, for the scope you described, **must be declared on top of a standard module** (in the declarations area). Then, it must be set **in a Sub**. After having a value it can be called from the UserForm code.

Comment: Yes, if I understood you correctly, that's exactly what I tried in the first way shown, I declared those two object before the Sub and then set them inside the Sub. It worked inside the Sub but when the userform initializes, it throws the error **"Object variable or with block variable not set"**

Comment: This can not be possible if you declared the variable as you say **in a standard module**. Not in the form or in a sheet module. There are a lot of other ways to use an object. You can declare as `Private` at the user form module level and define it during the form initialization `Set wb = Workbooks("MyWorkbook")`. You can also create public variables in the form and initialized them from the standard module Sub (`MyForm.wb = Workbooks("MyWorkbook")`. But if you need the specific workbook in many places, the way you tried looks the most appropriate.

Comment: It will also be good to check if it has a value and if not, to appropriately set it: `If N is Nothing then set N = Workbooks("MyWorkbook.xlsx")`. Or make a `Public Sub` in a standard module and call it: `Sub VarInitialization()` `Set N = Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New").Range("A1").Text)` `Set E = N.Sheets(1).ListObjects(1)` `End Sub`. And use this variant in the next way: `If N is Nothing then VarInitialization`.

Comment: Yes, it's a good check

Comment: When I said a `Public Sub`, being in a standard module it is public anyhow, except the case when it is created as `Private Sub VarInitialization()`.

Answer (score 3):

Add a `Sub` to your `UserForm` to set your `Workbook` and `ListObject` objects.

Userform:

```
Private pWB As Workbook
Private pLO As ListObject

Public Sub SetObjects(ByVal wb As Workbook, ByVal lo As ListObject)
    Set pWB = wb
    Set pLO = lo
End Sub
```

In your calling code:

```
Sub CallingCode()
    Dim UF As UserForm1 ' Don't use the global UserForm1 object
    Set UF = New UserForm1
    UF.SetObjects N, E
    UF.Show
End Sub
```